# Is there any contract to get USD value of Ether

Tags: ether, ethereumjs, usdt

I am looking for a contract address from where I can fetch current USD value of ether on fly, not looking for any api, so is there any contract for this ?

Comment: [ChainLink ETH/USD Oracle](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419#readContract).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is an **Oracle**. Check out [Tellor](https://tellor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UserSetup/%20%20). It's the simplest one out there to integrate directly in your contracts.

Comment: I agree totally with this answer. Tellor is excellent.